# Semantic UI react dropdown: Can you dynamically set the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using a dropdown from `semantic-ui-react`. The semantic-ui dropdown is in my `Artists` component and that component is being used its parent component, `App`.

Right now the dropdown is working fine, if you select a name (artist) from the dropdown then the `handleArtistSelection` function is called with that artist's name passed into it. Most of the code is below.

But is there another way to set the value of the dropdown? For example in jquery you can use:

```
$("#mydropdownlist").val("thevalue").change();
```

App Component

```
export default function App() {

     const handleArtistSelection = (artist) => {
        ...
     };

     const artistOptions = artistArray.map((artist) => { return {text: artist, value: artist} });

     return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Explore Music Award Show Winners</h1>
          <Artists options={artistOptions} onArtistChange={handleArtistSelection} placeholder={'Pick an artist'}/>
        </div>
     )

}
```

Artists Component:

```
import {Dropdown} from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default function Artists (props) {

    const handleOnChange = (e, data) => {
        props.onArtistChange(data.value);
    }

    return(
        <Dropdown placeholder={props.placeholder} search selection options={props.options} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about useRef, and call setState directly on the ref.

```
const countryOptions = [
  { key: "af", value: "af", flag: "af", text: "Afghanistan" },
  { key: "ax", value: "ax", flag: "ax", text: "Aland Islands" },
  { key: "al", value: "al", flag: "al", text: "Albania" },
  { key: "dz", value: "dz", flag: "dz", text: "Algeria" }
];

const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const handleClick = () => {
    ref.current.setState({ value: "dz" });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown
        ref={ref}
        placeholder="Select Country"
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryOptions}
      />
      <hr />
      <Button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Select Algeria
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```